# Can't add model object to jsp view in "/", but same method is working in call to /index

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Here is the link to the website I'm developing

35.200.161.123/ShahbazKhan/index

35.200.161.123/ShahbazKhan/  (see the latest news section for the problem)

both of them are the are handled by the same controller method and returns the same page.
The problem is the call to /index is working perfectly as it should be whereas the when I visit my website just as 35.200.161.123/ShahbazKhan/ the 'posts' object is not passed to the jsp.
Here is the code of the index controller

```
@Autowired
private PostService postService;

@RequestMapping(value={"/","index"})
public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest req){
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    List<Post> posts = postService.findLatest3();
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    mv.addObject("posts", posts);
    mv.addObject(session);
    return mv;
}
```

I'm I missing some configurations?? The project is build with Spring Boot

[img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Xuf.png)

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOh5E.png)

[Project Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jsUg.png)

Application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx/shahbazkhan
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password= xxxxxxxxxx
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 


spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: well obviously `ModelAndView("index")` this is a problem, I bet if you change `"index"` to `"/"` it will work the other way around. No idea how to fix this though, will be glad to find out myself :) grab a +1. The only thing that comes to my mind is to create a separate mapping for `"/"` with a simple jsp that redirects to `/index`. Which btw I thought was default behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the workaround the separate mapping for "/" to redirect to /index is one of the solution and is working fine..but I still could not figure out why the call to root "/" is not getting the object passed to the jsp view..because suppose I want the url bar to look clean as sitename.com not as sitename.com/index everytime a user visits my site..

Comment: In your web.xml, check for <welcome-file-list> tag and update the question with the contents. Is index.jsp included in the list? Also, are you using a view resolver?

Comment: @Fabulous I have not created web.xml file since it's a simple spring spring boot app as it's working without web.xml..can you just tell me what to add to <welcome-file-list> attribute to web.xml file? index.jsp is the index view for the application. I'm using a view resolver, I have updated the question with application.properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server's default behavior (that is, passing all requests like `35.200.161.123/ShahbazKhan/` to `35.200.161.123/ShahbazKhan/index`) is no longer applicable. All requests are passed to a controller, and are compared with the view resolver properties that you have supplied. The application server checks if the requested resource is available in WEB-INF folder, and returns the resource after processing.

If the resource is not found, the web server defaults to providing static pages.

Currently all of your views are publicly available under webapps folder, so while making a call to projectsite/ the index controller is not called, and you are served "index.html" as is, without the jsp object.

It is essential you put all Spring, Hibernate and other java resources in WEB-INF folder, as this folder is looked up whenever a request is passed. Reference: https://vitalflux.com/web-application-folder-structure-spring-mvc-web-projects/ ,  https://blogs.quovantis.com/spring-project-best-practices

Then, you must tell the application server to prefix all requests with `/WEB-INF/`. You must supply that property in your view resolver by changing `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /` to `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/`

Comment: I have updated the project structure in the question, I don't have my jsp files in the WEB-INF folder..Kindly have a look

Comment: It is essential you create a WEB-INF folder in webapp and put all contents in it. Take a look at this: http://blogs.quovantis.com/spring-project-best-practices/   and   https://vitalflux.com/web-application-folder-structure-spring-mvc-web-projects/

Comment: Thanks @Fabulous those were great resouces moving the views to WEB-INF solved the issue.

Comment: Now I finally figured out what the problem was actually all the views were in the root of the webapps folder which were publicly available so I guess while making a call to projectsite/ the index controller is not called, instead the server's default behavior is serving the index file that is why the model object is not there in the view as the index method was never called, Right??

Comment: Exactly. That is why we must put all contents in WEB-INF folder, so that the request after being processed by the controller can return something from WEB-INF